# Images not aligning properly in grid - Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a mini project to recreate a website using bootstrap 4. I am on a part where I need to have three images in a grid format two on the top and one on the bottom. The top two should be even by height (not width the image on the right is larger) like the image below:

[image: How the site should look]

Notice how on the bottom (they are even at the top) they are perfectly even.

Now here is how mine looks:

[image: How mine looks]

See how the image on the left looks it is slightly higher then the one on the right.

Here is my code for that portion:

```
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="assets/home_seasonal_1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" >
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="assets/home_seasonal_2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <img src="assets/home_seasonal_3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have tried different variations of the columns and nothing has worked so far. The goal is to do this without modifying the css and only using bootstrap.

Here is the bootstrap version I am using:

> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

I just need some guidance on how I can make this happen.

Here are the images:

[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: last image]

Comment: Are those two top images same height?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `.img-fluid`, it sets the max width to 100% and the height auto. That means, if the box that contains the image is narrow, the image might be scaled down and so is the height.

Also I realize, from your expected image, the top 2 pictures are shown from the bottom up while the last 1 is shown from top down.

Those points make me want to use those images as the `background` of those columns instead.

#### Structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <!-- assets/home_seasonal_1.jpg -->
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5PIq.jpg') center bottom /cover no-repeat"></div>
        <!-- assets/home_seasonal_2.jpg -->
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVUvf.jpg') center bottom/cover no-repeat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <!-- assets/home_seasonal_3.jpg -->
        <div class="col-md-10" style="background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhMX6.jpg') center top/cover no-repeat"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

#### Style

I am being lazy here to style them this way, but you can do inline css to set different styles for those columns. And I used white borders here to do the trick.

```
.row {
    height: 12rem;
}

[class*="col-md"] {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

#### Result

LOL it almost looks the same as your expected outcome!
[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/144953/